# Connect MongoDB with Mongoose. but return... const Schema = require('./schema');

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've install Mongoose to connect MongoDB from node.js

but after server started, it's return error like this.

I'd checked index.js file in node_modules/mongoose/lib.

It had 'use strict' already

```
/root/public/node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:7
const Schema = require('./schema');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/public/node/node_modules/mongoose/index.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

If somebody ever found this error, please tell me how to fix it.
Thank you

Comment: what is your node version? it think you need to update your node version

Comment: `const` is not supported by ECMAScript. So after you specify strict mode, you get syntax error. You need to use `var` instead of const if you want your code to be compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `nodejs` will solve the issue:

```
npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
node --version
node app.js
```

You have to run the second and third command as root/administrator.